# $4011x+42053 \equiv 2x-782398 \pmod {10}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

$4011x+42053 \equiv 2x-782398 \pmod {10}$

$10|(4011x+42053-2x+782398) \space \rightarrow \space 10|(4009x + 824451)$

$\rightarrow\space 4009x\equiv -824451 \pmod {10}$

I am dubious about this next step: $4009x \equiv 9 \pmod {10}$???

If true: inverse of $4009 \pmod{10} = 9$

So, $x \equiv 81 \pmod{10} \space\rightarrow\space x\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$

Is this correct?

Comment: $x+3 \equiv 2 x - 8 \pmod {10}$

Comment: 4000=10(400)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just reduce all the constants modulo $10$ before doing anything else: $4011 \equiv 1\pmod{10}$, $42053\equiv 3\pmod{10}$, $-782398\equiv -8\pmod{10}$, so your equation becomes $x + 3 \equiv 2x-8\pmod{10}$. This simplifies to $x\equiv 11\equiv 1\pmod{10}$, as you said.

Comment: why is it possible to do this? reduce all modulo 10 even though they are being added or subtracted

Comment: For example, $42053 = 4205\cdot 10 + 3$. Plug that into the original equation. Do you see that you can just "ignore" the 4205\cdot 10 since you are working $\pmod{10}$?

Comment: @Oiclid I would imagine this is one of the first properties of modular arithmetic you should have learned.  For addition, $(10q_1+r_1)+(10q_2+r_2)=10(q_1+q_2)+r_1+r_2\equiv r_1+r_2\pmod{10}$.  Multiplication can be similarly proven.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is correct, but it fails to employ the many optimizations possible. Namely, in expressions composed of sums and products, you can replace any summand or multiplicand by any congruent number. For example, modulo $10$, since $\,\color{#c00}{4011\equiv 1}$, the product $\,\color{#c00}{4011}x\equiv \color{#c00}1\cdot x\equiv x.$ Further $\,\color{#0a0}{42053\equiv 3},$ so $\,\color{#c00}{4211x}+\color{#0a0}{42053}\equiv \color{#c00}x + \color{#0a0}3$ by replacing each summand by their simpler congruent values. Doing the same to the RHS yields $\,x+3\equiv 2x-8,\,$ thus $\,x\equiv 11\equiv 1.$

Below are proofs of said congruence rules. *Beware* that such rules need not hold true for other operations, e.g.
the exponential analog of below $\rm A^B\equiv a^b$ is not generally true (unless $\rm B = b)$.

**Congruence Sum Rule** $\rm\qquad\  A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{A+B\equiv a+b}\ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\:\ \ m\: |\: A-a,\ B-b\:\ \Rightarrow\:\ m\ |\ (A-a) + (B-b)\ =\ \color{#0a0}{A+B - (a+b)} $

**Congruence Product Rule** $\rm\ \ A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}{AB\equiv ab}\ \ (mod\ m)$

**Proof** $\rm\:\ \ m\: |\: A-a,\ B-b\:\ \Rightarrow\:\ m\ |\ (A-a)\ B + a\ (B-b)\ =\ \color{#c00}{AB - ab} $

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. In your dubious step you just take $4009x\equiv -824451 \equiv 9 \mod 10$. Furthermore, then directly follows for $x=1$ that $4009x\equiv 9 \mod 10$. (Just look at the last digit of the number)

Answer (score 0):

The set of solutions of your equation is $\{10k+1\hspace{2mm}/\hspace{2mm}k\in \mathbb N\} $

Answer (score 0):

$4011x+42053\equiv2x-782398 \rightarrow x+3\equiv2x-(-2)\rightarrow x\equiv1$

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would help the OP.

Comment: but it's super short and straight to the point.